# Format Document on View inserts "ExternalSource" Directive

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, visual-studio-2015

I have an issue I've recently noticed in visual studio (2015 Enterprise) where when I'm working on a View and I format a document using the "Format Document" functionality either through the keyboard shortcut or the edit menu, that visual studio will add in one or more External Source Directives throughout the document e.g.:

```
#End ExternalSource

#ExternalSource ("C:\ProjectLocation\CurrentView.vbhtml",12)
```

The End statement also comes before the start statement, even if there isn't another start above it. The number is not usually the same, and reading up it's a line number.

I assume this has something to do with having code in the View (using Razor), but is there a way to prevent this from happening when I'm formatting a View, as it's frustrating and it doesn't even format the document correctly!

Comment: Also applies to code without Razor both in views and .vb files (VS 2015 Pro).

Comment: Error exists in VS2017. Bug has been added by someone to the MS bug tracker (and then ignored): https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/205742/text-including-end-external-source-is-added-to-vb.html.

Comment: Nice to see they've acknowledged it at least, though disheartening that not much has happened. Cheers @Marcus.

Comment: it's November and still an issue..

Comment: Issue persists in VS2019

Comment: still an issue in 2021. happens "sometimes"

Comment: still happens in version 2022, and burning away way too much precious time and ruining chucks of code. its almost impossible to use VS anymore with out project.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this happens when I'm doing a lot of databinding in the aspx code:

```
Text='<%# Eval("MyFieldName") %>'
```

Perhaps cutting and pasting blocks in a malformed way is causing this.

I'm thinking that when the `eval` is executed when running, .net is inserting this external code into the aspx page, but if the page hits an error or crashes somehow, the external code isn't removed and remains all sliced up within the raw aspx.

Not sure if that makes sense.  Just spent hours trying to scrape this code out (which kept reappearing) before giving up and reverting to a previous version and starting over.